# How do you pass an array though a function in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, function, integer, nsnumber

I need some help. I am new to Objective-C and trying to learn how to program iPhone Applications in Xcode 3.0.
I am trying to pass my array through a function and am confused. Thank you for your help.
Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void add(int x) {
    NSLog(@"%i + 2 = %i", x, x + 2);
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 NSNumber *arrayNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5];
 NSNumber *arrayNumber2 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:9];

 NSMutableArray *arrayNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

 [arrayNumbers addObject:arrayNumber];
 [arrayNumbers addObject:arrayNumber2];



 NSLog(@"object at index 0 = %i", [[arrayNumbers objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
 NSLog(@"object at index 1 = %i", [[arrayNumbers objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);



for(NSNumber *answer in arrayNumbers) {
    add();
}


return 0;
}
```

I am confused by what to put in the parentheses in the part with add():

```
for(NSNumber *answer in arrayNumbers) {
    add();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unbox the `NSNumber` using  [`-intValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/intValue) like this:

```
for(NSNumber *answer in arrayNumbers) {
    add([answer intValue]);
}
```